# Get custom user data from Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I know

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

will return a UserDetails object which is fine to get the user name. But lets suppose I need more data from my custom user object (MyUser). Which is the right way to get MyUser from a UserDetails object, being for example, UserDetails just provide name but the same name can be used by more than one user.
I mean if I search in my MyUser's repository using just name it can return more than one user.

Answer (score 1):

This username doesn't mean real username. The "name" of a Principal is usually something unique. For example, it can be userId.

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    String userName = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hatice, trying to probe your answer I found it is returning userId, which belongs to UserDetails interface.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast your custom UserDetails Object , For eg, Customer Object in my case implements UserDetails Object.

```
 Customer userDetails = (Customer)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().
           getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

My WebSecurityConfig is

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomAuthoritiesPopulator customerAuthPopulator;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        auth.ldapAuthentication().ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(customerAuthPopulator)
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                .userDnPatterns("CN={0},OU=People,DC=com").contextSource()
                .url("ldap://myCompanyAD-Domain:389");


    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsContextMapper();
    }

}
```

CustomUserDetailsContextMapper Implementation

```
@Configuration
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public LdapUserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        log.info("LdapUserDetails start");
        LdapUserDetailsImpl details = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
        Customer user = new Customer(details);
        // details = (Customer) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
        try {
            user.setDisplayName(ctx.getStringAttribute("displayName"));
            user.setEmail(ctx.getStringAttribute("mail"));
            user.setPhone(ctx.getStringAttribute("telephoneNumber"));
            user.setOrgUnit(ctx.getStringAttribute("division"));

            log.info("DN from ctx: " + ctx.getDn()); // return correct DN

            for (NamingEnumeration attr = ctx.getAttributes().getAll(); attr.hasMore();) {
                Attribute attribute = (Attribute) attr.next();
                log.info("Attribute id: " + attribute.getID());

                for (NamingEnumeration val = attribute.getAll(); val.hasMore();) {
                    log.info("Attribute value: " + val.next());
                }

            }
            log.info("Attributes size: " + ctx.getAttributes().size()); // always returns 0
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.error("Exception Caught", e);
        }
        return user;
    }

@Override
public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
    // default
}
```

}

Customer Implementation

```
@Component
public class Customer implements LdapUserDetails {

    private String DisplayName;
    private String Email;
    private String Phone;
    private String OrgUnit;

    private LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapCtx;


    public Customer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Customer(LdapUserDetailsImpl copyMe ) {
        super();
        ldapCtx = copyMe;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [DisplayName=" + DisplayName + ", Email=" + Email + ", Phone=" + Phone + ", OrgUnit=" + OrgUnit
                + "] LdapUserDetails [" + ldapCtx.toString() + "]";
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return DisplayName;
    }
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }
    public String getOrgUnit() {
        return OrgUnit;
    }
    public void setOrgUnit(String orgUnit) {
        OrgUnit = orgUnit;
    }



    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
         list.add((new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
     return list;  
    }



    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.getPassword();
    }



    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.getUsername();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.isAccountNonExpired();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.isAccountNonLocked();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.isEnabled();
    }



    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public String getDn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ldapCtx.getDn();
    }




}
```